# Refreshing xml via jquery over console

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have created the following script to parse my xml and then to start a certain script, once I type in `start();` in my console:

```
window.start = function (data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "test.xml",
        async: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: Template
    });

    jQuery('#test').Test({
    });

};
```

this part works perfectly, but what I would like it to do is basically refresh the xml each time `start();` is called. At the moment it is obviously not doing this as in if data is adjusted in the xml they are not showing.

Any ideas as in how this can be done? If it means I have to type in the `test.xml` inside the `start();` how can that be done but if there there is another way please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself basically I don't refresh I basically empty it out..

hence i use before the parser

```
if ($('#test').html()) {
   $('body').empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set async to true or not declare it as it's true by default:

```
async: true,
```

Comment: While this is good practice, it has no bearing on the OPs question.

Comment: unfortunately that does not work. I still have to refresh the browser (f5) and then type start.